# How to create a Dataframe from rows with conditions from another existing Dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this problem, because of the size of the dataframe that I am working on, clearly, I cannot upload it, but it has the following structure:

|  | country | coastline | EU | highest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Norway | yes | yes | 1500 |
| 2 | Turkey | yes | no | 20100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 41 | Bolivia | no | no | 999 |
| 42 | Japan | yes | no | 89 |

I have to solve several exercises with Pandas, among them is, for example, showing the country with the "highest" maximum, minimum and the average but only of the countries that do belong to the EU, I already solved the maximum and the minimum, but for the middle I thought about creating a new dataframe, one that is created from only the rows that contain a "yes" in the EU column, I've tried a few things, but they haven't worked.

I thought this is the best way to solve it, but if anyone has another idea, I'm looking forward to reading it.

By the way, these are the examples that I said that I was able to solve:

```
print('Minimum outside the EU')
paises[(paises.EU == "no")].sort_values(by=['highest'], ascending=[True]).head(1)
```

Which gives me this:

|  | country | coastline | EU | highest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Belarus | no | no | 345 |

As a last condition, this must be solved using pandas, since it is basically the chapter that we are working on in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new dataframe that is based off of a filter on your first, you can do this:

```py
new_df = df[df['EU'] == 'yes'].copy()
```

This will look at the 'EU' column in the original dataframe `df`, and only return the rows where it is 'yes'. I think it is good practice to add the `.copy()` since we can sometimes get strange side-affects if we then make changes to `new_df` (probably wouldn't here).

Comment: if you upvote the answer & mark it complete, others will also know the answer helped you and that the question has been answered.